# Populating File Name With Values in Cell for an External Reference in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two Excel workbooks and I need a few cells in one to pull data from a few cells in another file.  What I cannot figure out is how to structure the formula that will reference a specific workbook based upon the values in certain cells within the workbook that will be calling out to the external file.  For example, if the value in a cell is Week 1, I need the file name to reference the Week 1 file.  Similarly, if the value in a cell is Week 2, I need the file name to reference Week 2.  Is VBA needed to do this or can I simply use a formula?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the INDIRECT formula which takes a string and makes it into a reference. So you can make the string inside the INDIRECT into a formula based on whatever parameters you want and as long as the string you create matches that of an actual workbook it should pull the reference. Not sure how it works with closed workbooks though.

Comment: I have entered "='Z:\Financials\Sales\Cashier Return Sheets\FY2017\03\[week4.xlsx]Thursday 1'!$C$40" and this is working as an alternative to the INDIRECT function, as I am working with closed workbooks, but now I have the question: how do I ask Excel to pull the data from cells in the active sheet for use in this formula.  For instance, ='Drive:\path\Sales\Cashier Return Sheets\FY2017\(use value from cell) \[(use value from cell).xlsx]Thursday 1'!$C$40?